# Does CakePHP model validation not work when $useTable = false?

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, model

Recently I have worked on two CakePHP web applications. The first I used tables in the format CakePHP required them and validation seems to be working correctly. For the second application I am using `$useTable = false` and instead using the [model name]->query() function to execute SQL stored procedures inside the controllers to save and update data but have come across several issues with model validation.

**Example 1:**
I have a field called 'WeekName' that has a limit of 50 characters in the database. My model validation is setup as shown below which matches the Cake documentation and yet it happily lets a string length of more than 50 characters tried to be saved.

```
'WeekName' => array(
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'rule' => array('maxLength', '50'),
        'message' => 'No more than 50 characters long.'
    ),`
```

**Example 2:**
I created question recently regarding adding validation where one of two fields needed to contain data in order for the controller to process the data. After trying several suggestions nothing has worked and it doesn't check the validation at all and just proceeds to process the code in the controller function.

[Link to posted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526845/way-to-check-at-least-one-of-x-field-validation-in-cakephp)

All of these issues have led me to wonder if model validation is ignored when `$useTable = false` and whether this is done intentionally and if there is a way I can turn on model validation if this is the case.

If anyone has any insight on this issue and what could be causing it or if there is a possible solution that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

**Notes:**

Developing with CakePHP 2.7

Comment: You've stated your using `query()` to update your tables but not mentioned how you are attempting to validate your data. You need to show some of your code. Also, why if your models have associated tables are you telling Cake there is no table and manually querying the database?

Comment: Make sure you state which version of CakePHP you are developing with too.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja Example 1 is an example of the validation I am trying to do inside the `$validate` array in the model. My question is focused on whether of not `$useTable = false` causes issues with model validation rather than my validation not working.

Comment: Example 1 just shows a validation rule, not how you are validating your data!

Comment: Surely if my validation rule is using one of CakePHPs built in validation rules, which maxLength is then the validating of the data is being handled for me?

Comment: You need to show a call to save or validate - if you have no call to save or validate you're asking about code that is currently irrelevant to what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CakePHP validation rules will work for models with no table. However, it looks like you're not running validation on your data before saving it with `$this->ModelName->query()`. Unlike `save()`, `query()` will not automatically run validation before saving as it does not use CakePHP's callbacks to test the data.

Unless really necessary I'd avoid manually querying the database with `query()` and use `save()` but if you need to do this then you will have to manually validate too:-

```
$this->ModelName->set($this->request->data);
if ($this->ModelName->validates()) {
    // Save your data using query()
    $this->ModelName->query();
} else {
    // Validation failed
}
```

This sets the data against the model and then runs the set data against the model's validation rules. If successful it will run your `query()`.

See [Validating Data from the Controller](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html) in the docs for more details.